# What is the best way to measure the memory used when a function runs in sage?

Tags: memory, memory-management, sage

I'm looking to measure a few different methods to achieve the same goal, and the main criteria I've been given is that the program has to use up as little memory as possible. I've tried looking online but the only memory related aspect I can find is dealing with low-level memory allocations.

Is there a function or method to accurately get the memory usage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is!  Here is an example from [one of the Sage tickets trying to track down memory leaks](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/501):

```
print get_memory_usage()
K = GF(10007^2, 'a')
X = PolynomialRing(K, 'x').gen()
for i in range(1000):
   s = K.random_element(); t = K.random_element()
   poly = s + t*X
print get_memory_usage()
```

I think there is more sophisticated use possible (e.g. using Valgrind, which was an optional package that used to at least work with Sage), so I cannot say if this is the *best* way to measure it, but it should be a good place to start.